# increment name if name exists mysql

Tags: mysql

i have document table with structure as

```
CREATE TABLE document_history 
(
 id int auto_increment primary key, 
 document_id int,
 name varchar(100),
 modified datetime,
 user_id int 
 );
```

and following values

```
ID   |  DOCUMENT_ID  |  NAME              |  MODIFIED     |   USER_ID
33   |  81           |  document.docx     |  2014-03-21   |   1
34   |  82           |  doc.docx          |  2014-03-21   |   1
35   |  82           |  doc(1).docx       |  2014-03-21   |   1
36   |  82           |  doc(2).docx       |  2014-03-21   |   1
```

So when a user upload file with name doc.docx then it should be renamed as doc(3).docx and so on and so forth.

I am trying to write query which will give me next increment for my file name. have tried regxps but still not able achieve through query. Also my table can have millions of required however with some filter criteria.

Comment: You could add a `version` column

Comment: `VARCHAR(100)` is probably way too short here. Use `VARCHAR(255)` as a safe default, and possibly `VARCHAR(1024)` if you have users with *creative* naming conventions.

Comment: its not duplicate. I need to rename before inserting records. While the link shared is about renaming value within db, there is lot of difference between 2 questions

Comment: @RiaAnggraini It's a copy/paste job, even the schema is copied out of one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

This will find the document name for a given document id then does an incremental counter to assign a new document name (version). I sort the result by record id then display only the latest (and new) document name.

```
select t.new_name
from (
     select id, 
            concat(
                   case when locate('(',name)>0 
                        then left(name,locate('(',name)-1) 
                        else left(name,locate('.',name)-1) end,
                        '(',
                        @rownum := @rownum + 1,
                        ')',
                        right(name,locate('.',reverse(name)))) as new_name
              from document_history, 
                  (select  @rownum := 0) r
              where document_id=81
      ) t
order by t.id desc
limit 1;

Result:
for document_id=81:   document(1).docx
for document_id=82:   doc(3).docx
```

Comment: Yes. This answer my query to some extent. Not sure whether this will have performance impact for million records.

Comment: if you are searching by document_id and table has an index on document_id, then it should not be a problem. the sub-query will be depending on how many document_id exists.  HOWEVER, test it to confirm our theory.